# Как открыть 2-е окно, созданное в Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, pyside2

Как открыть второе окно?

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from ui import Ui_Start
import time

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


Start = QtGui.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Start()
ui.setupUi(Start)
Start.show()
def but_1():
   from ui import Ui_inst
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

   inst = QtGui.QWidget()
   ui_ins = Ui_inst()
   ui_ins.setupUi(inst)
   inst.show()
   ui_ins.textEdit.setText("12546")

   sys.exit(app.exec_())

   ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect( but_1 )     

   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
#from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from ui_start import Ui_Start
from ui_inst  import Ui_Inst


class StartWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Start):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)   

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect( self.but_1 )

    def but_1(self):

        self.inst = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        ui_ins = Ui_Inst()
        ui_ins.setupUi(self.inst)
        self.inst.show()
        ui_ins.textEdit.setText("12546")        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = StartWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**ui_start.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Start(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_Start):
        Ui_Start.setObjectName("Ui_Start")
        Ui_Start.resize(306, 212)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Ui_Start)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 36, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(85, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Ui_Start)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(85, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 37, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 36, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem4, 4, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Ui_Start)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Ui_Start)

    def retranslateUi(self, Ui_Start):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Ui_Start.setWindowTitle(_translate("Ui_Start", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "Start"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "Открыть 2-е окно"))
```

---

**ui_inst.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Inst(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_Inst):
        Ui_Inst.setObjectName("Ui_Inst")
        Ui_Inst.resize(310, 229)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Ui_Inst)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Ui_Inst)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Inst)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Ui_Inst)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Ui_Inst)

    def retranslateUi(self, Ui_Inst):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Ui_Inst.setWindowTitle(_translate("Ui_Inst", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Ui_Inst", "PushButton"))
```

---

**Update**:

```
import sys
#from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from ui_start import Ui_Start
class Ui_Start(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_Start):
        Ui_Start.setObjectName("Ui_Start")
        Ui_Start.resize(306, 212)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Ui_Start)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 36, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(85, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Ui_Start)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(85, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 37, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Start)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 36, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem4, 4, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Ui_Start)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Ui_Start)

    def retranslateUi(self, Ui_Start):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Ui_Start.setWindowTitle(_translate("Ui_Start", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "Start"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Ui_Start", "Открыть 2-е окно"))


#from ui_inst  import Ui_Inst
class Ui_Inst(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_Inst):
        Ui_Inst.setObjectName("Ui_Inst")
        Ui_Inst.resize(310, 229)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Ui_Inst)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Ui_Inst)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Ui_Inst)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Ui_Inst)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Ui_Inst)

    def retranslateUi(self, Ui_Inst):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Ui_Inst.setWindowTitle(_translate("Ui_Inst", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Ui_Inst", "PushButton"))


class StartWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Start):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)   

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect( self.but_1 )

    def but_1(self):

        self.inst = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        ui_ins = Ui_Inst()
        ui_ins.setupUi(self.inst)
        self.inst.show()
        ui_ins.textEdit.setText("12546")        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = StartWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: from ui_start import Ui_Start
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ui_start'

Comment: @5478512 так сохраните модуль `ui_start.py` в текущий каталог, туда же где и модуль `main.py`. Обратите внимание, что все написано маленькими буквами.

Comment: теперь программа не открывается.
C:\Users\Danila>"C:\for cheacher\sentense.py"
C:\Users\Danila>"C:\for cheacher\sentense.py"
C:\Users\Danila>"C:\for cheacher\sentense.py"
C:\Users\Danila>"C:\for cheacher\sentense.py"

Comment: @5478512 я собрал все в один модуль, попробуйте обновление. Потом разберетесь с отдельными файлами модулей.